# Can an Elementalist benefit from "sorcerous reserves?"

Tags: dnd-4e

Elementalists receive no daily powers. As a sorcerer, they qualify for the paragon feat [Sorcerous Reserves](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1187):

> Benefit: When you have expended all your sorcerer daily attack powers, you gain a +1 bonus to attack rolls with sorcerer at-will attack powers until you regain the use of one of your sorcerer daily attack powers.

What benefit to they derive from this feat, if any?

Comment: Tip to any optimizers looking at this: With academy master, hellfire blood, and arcane spellfury, this feat is made functionally redundant, as the PP and heroic feat provide a 94% accuracy with an 18 (post-racial) in the primary stat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a character has no daily spells to "expend", then the benefit would never take affect.

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: I agree with this.  It states that you have to expend them, and as an Elementalist, you can't expend daily powers.  Ergo, you can't get the benefit.

Comment: If the feet read "while you have no daily sorcerer powers available" or some thing similar, you would gain its benefit. But it doesn't so you don't.